# What does the ! operator do in this situation?

Tags: c

I am learning C from a textbook, and I stumbled onto the code of a function, where the following part had little explanation to what it does. It looked something like this:

```
int func(char *a, char *b) {
    if(!a || !b)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

My understanding is it checks that `a` and `b` are not null? Is this correct? Any help is welcome for this beginner :)

Comment: I don't get the downvote, the question is absolutely fine for a beginner.

Comment: If *either* of them is `NULL`. But it would be better to be explicit: `if(a == NULL || b == NULL)`. The function returns `1` if both pointers are valid.

Comment: @CherryDT NULL evaluates to the address zero, not the number zero.

Comment: @WeatherVane No worries! :)

Answer (score 4):

`!` is the logical not operator.

The `if` condition `!a || !b` is true if either `a` or `b` are zero, i.e. `NULL` pointers. Then the `func` returns `0` in that case, `1` otherwise:

```
a        b        condition  func
null     null     true       0
null     non-null true       0
non-null null     true       0
non-null non-null false      1
```

It is easier to understand if you negate the condition and swap the return values:

```
int func(char *a, char *b) {
    if(a && b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Since in C the relational operators give their result as an `int`, i.e. `0` for false and `1` for true, you can simplify further to:

```
int func(char *a, char *b) {
    return a && b;
}
```

Comment: This is a very clear answer and the code "simplifications" are great! Thank you!

Comment: @anInputName You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  When a is null or b is null then the logical NOT operator will cause the if conditional to evaluate as true and the return value is zero, otherwise the code returns 1 indicating that either a or b is not null.

Answer (score -1):

The `!` operator in most programming languages reverses the logic(or the not operator).  i.e.(From True to False or vice versa)

For example:

```
a=True;
if(!a) {
    return 1;
}else {
    return 2;
}
```

Output is 2. So in this case, you are saying if not A OR not B, return 0.